# gestureRecognizer not working on added subview

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uibezierpath

I'm adding a subview in a view that holds multiple gesturerecognizer however when this view is being introduced the gesture's won't fire when the user taps inside this newly added view. It's a `UIBezierPath` that I'm introducing however. I've read that this could be way it doesn't work. My question is, is it possible to make the added `UIBezierPath` transparent in a way that the device will think the view below the drawn box is being tapped. I hope it makes sense what I'm saying.

This is the code for my `UIBezierPath`

```
class drawRecognizerIndicator{
let gestureContainer: UIView!
var view_gesture: UIView!

init(container: UIView){
    gestureContainer = container
}

func drawRect(image: UIImage){
    let screenSize = gestureContainer.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height

    let gestureX = (screenWidth * 0.75) * 0.5
    let gestureY = (screenWidth * 0.75) * 0.5
    let gestureWidth = (screenWidth * 0.75)
    let gestureHeight = (screenWidth * 0.75)

    if(view_gesture != nil){
        if(view_gesture.isDescendantOfView(gestureContainer)){
            view_gesture.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    view_gesture = UIView(frame: CGRect(
        x: (screenWidth * 0.5) - gestureX,
        y: (screenHeight * 0.5) - gestureY ,
        width: gestureWidth,
        height: gestureHeight))
    view_gesture.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    view_gesture.alpha = 0

    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view_gesture.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: maskPath)
    maskLayer.frame = view_gesture.bounds
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath
    view_gesture.layer.mask = maskLayer

    let view_gestureSize = view_gesture.bounds
    let gestureIconWidth = view_gestureSize.width
    let gestureIconHeight = view_gestureSize.height

    let iconX = (gestureIconWidth * 0.8) * 0.5
    let iconY = (gestureIconHeight * 0.8) * 0.5
    let iconWidth = gestureIconWidth * 0.8
    let iconHeight = gestureIconHeight * 0.8

    let image_gesture = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(
        x: (gestureIconWidth * 0.5) - iconX,
        y: (gestureIconHeight * 0.5) - iconY,
        width: iconWidth,
        height: iconHeight))
    image_gesture.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    image_gesture.image = image
    image_gesture.userInteractionEnabled = true
    view_gesture.addSubview(image_gesture)
    view_gesture.userInteractionEnabled = true
    gestureContainer.addSubview(view_gesture)
    animateGestureNotification(view_gesture)
}

func animateGestureNotification(view_gesture: UIView){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        view_gesture.alpha = 0.4
        }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        view_gesture.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: hello ,have you  check userInteractionEnabled = Yes

Comment: @Akash yeah I did. In the last few lines of code of the drawrect func you can find this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
 shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer
 otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {...}
```

It helps to decide what happens when there are several gesture recognizers on the same view controller.

I would start by putting some print statements in there to see exactly which GRs are being called, and then decide which ones should return true.

Comment: The gesture recognizers do work fine when the drawrect isn't being called. They still work when you will work around the box that will appear in your view. However when the user will use the same gesture inside this box it won't fire the gesture recognizer. While this is being added as a subview of the view that holds the gesture recognizers. Which have been added programmatically. Hope that clears it up a lil